# TTTableViewController with custom cell sample

Tags: iphone, three20

I am having difficulties in using TTTableViewController with a custom cell? In order to use a custom cell then can I use a UITableViewCell or do I have to subclass TTTableViewCell? How do I use TTModel? Is there any good examples out there that shows all of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest issue with TTTableViewCell is that it works completely different from the standard UITableViewCell & UITableViewDelegate, so you will have to forget what you know about UITableViewCell.

In nutshell, `TTTableItem` classes are data containers, while `TTTableItemCell` classes are responsible for displaying the cells in the table.

For example, `TTTableMessageItem` class contains all the data about a message, such as date, title and body. The `TTTableMessageItemCell` class contains all the UI elements for the cell and their layout.

I found it to be more flexible than the standard `UITableViewController`, because you can easily change cell types.

If you want to add your own custom class type, you will need to define both a new `TTTableItem` subclass and new `TTTableItemCell` subclass.

**HelloTableItem.h** - contains the data for the cell:

```
@interface HelloTableItem : TTTableLinkedItem {
NSString *_title;
NSString *_subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

+ (id)itemWithTitle:(NSString *)title
       subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle;

@end
```

**HelloTableItemCell.h** - the cell itself

```
@interface HelloTableItemCell : TTTableLinkedItemCell {
    UILabel *_titleLabel;
    UILabel *_subtitleLabel;
}

@end
```

**HelloTableViewDataSource.m** - The datasource is responsible to add the table items and to decide which type of cell to use for each item type

```
- (id)init {

if (self = [super init]) {
    self.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              [HelloTableItem itemWithTitle:@"First" subtitle:@"Hello #1!"],
              [HelloTableItem itemWithTitle:@"Second" subtitle:@"Hello #2!"],
              [HelloTableItem itemWithTitle:@"Third" subtitle:@"Hello #3!"],
              [HelloTableItem itemWithTitle:@"Fourth" subtitle:@"Hello #4!"],
              [HelloTableItem itemWithTitle:@"Fifth" subtitle:@"Hello #5!"],
              nil];
}

return self;
 }

- (Class)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellClassForObject:(id) object {

if ([object isKindOfClass:[HelloTableItem class]]) {  
    return [HelloTableItemCell class];  
}

return [super tableView:tableView cellClassForObject:object];
}

@end
```

The complete source code can be found here:
http://three20.pypt.lt/custom-cells-in-tttableviewcontroller